# XSL-FO different column-gap on same page

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm flowing text across four columns per page, using XSL-FO, with a typical definition like:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="sample" page-height="8.5in" page-width="11.0in" margin="8mm">
 <fo:region-body column-count="4" column-gap="4mm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

Is it possible to set the column-gap between the second and third column (for example) to be a different size than the column-gaps between the other columns?

If there is no official way of doing this, is there a way to "fake it"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the spec for `column-gap` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#column-gap), and I don't know of any XSL formatter that implements it.

One way to fake it would be to use multiple `fo:region-body` and a flow map that directs the content to each region in turn.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fafm.  For your different column gap between the second and third columns, you would need two two-column `fo:region-body`.  Not every XSL formatter implements flow maps, however, plus you couldn't have content with `span="all"` that would span across all the columns: at best, it would span across all of the columns in one of the `fo:region-body`.